# What is the use of ClassValue<T> in java?

Tags: java, class, java.lang.class

I currently looking to master every classes in Java.lang but couldn't understand the use of ClassValue. I have seen the official documentation, it says,

> public abstract class ClassValue
>   extends Object
>
> Lazily associate a computed value with (potentially) every type. For example, if a dynamic language needs to construct a message dispatch table for each class encountered at a message send call site, it can use a ClassValue to cache information needed to perform the message send quickly, for each class encountered.

Please help me, I am very curious..

Comment: I use the class quite a bit for caching information about a class. I used it yesterday so I could cache an array of all the interfaces for a class without having to recreate it each time.

Comment: Suppose, you have to do certain Reflective operation and want to cache a particular result. Normally, you would use a `WeakHashMap` for associating the `Class` object with the result of your analyzation, but in this special case, the resulting objects are likely to have references to the key class (as dispatch tables have). `ClassValue` allows associations with a `Class`, which do *not* hinder garbage collection. I have a use case, where all members having a particular annotation are gathered and a certain factory is generated based on these. Later on, the factory can be used without that step